# Arduino Display Issue

Tags: arduino

When I run my code the Arduino IDE gives me the error:

> exit status 1
>
> 'POSITIVE' was not declared in this scope.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/yvDEZWd3

Here is the part of the code I am having issues with:

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE); // 0x27 is the i2c address of the LCM1602 IIC v1 module (might differ)
```

Comment: You haven't defined/declared the `POSITIVE` variable. What's it supposed to be? Seems as though you want a define for it: `#define POSITIVE 3` (replace "3" with whatever value it should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined/declared the `POSITIVE` variable. What's it supposed to be? Seems as though you want a define for it:

```
#define POSITIVE 3
```

Replace "3" with whatever value it should be.

Comment: The problem is that it is a new library with old code, simply replace code with: LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);